# spring submodule bean not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, component-scan

I am having DemoService class in `test-client` module. Injecting this DemoService class from `test-server` module.

**1st case(working):**

Both `test-server` and `test-client` has root package as `com.demo.test` .

This case all the beans are loading.

**2nd case: (working after component scan)**

`test-server` has root package as `com.demo.test` .

`test-client` has root package as  `com.client.test`

This case  `test-client` beans are not loading. Expecting to `ComponentScan`.

**3rd case: (not working even after component scan)**

`test-client` module using one of the bean from `test-server`. this is not loading after `@ComponentScan` also.

How to overcome above scenarios?

Note:
I have imported sub modules in build.gradle

`implementation project(':test-client')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if `test-client` does not share the same base packages (defined by the package where your `@SpringBootApplication` class resides), then you will need to use `ComponentScan` in your `test-server` project:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.client.test")
```

A good alternative would we to create your own Spring Boot starter project for the client code as described in [section "Creating Your Own Auto-configuration" in the official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration).

Comment: Added one more case